# Clamping to rails of an unpowered circuit?

Tags: diode-clamp

Clamping diodes are a common way to limit an input to a safe voltage range: if the input goes below 0V or above 3.3V, one of the diodes begins to conduct and clamps the input to (roughly) the rails.

What happens if the circuit is unpowered? My 3.3V is generated using an async buck converter that doesn't have any low-impedance path to GND, and DigIn2 is connected to an ESP32. If the input is still active with a voltage of, say, 12V or 24V, wouldn't the same voltage be present at the MCU input? Wouldn't that be enough to damage the MCU, even with the current-limiting input resistor?

I believe an alternative would be to use a zener diode to clamp the voltage, but low-voltage zeners are so soft that I'd rather avoid them, if possible.

[image: Typical clamping diode setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If the input is still active with a voltage of, say, 12V or 24V,
> wouldn't the same voltage be present at the MCU input?*

Even if your circuit is powered, because you are using a non-synchronous buck regulator (or a standard linear regulator for instance) it won't prevent the rail voltage rising above where it should be unless your circuit current consumption and the 47 kΩ form enough of a potential divider to restrict this problem.

If your inputs are 12 volts or 24 volts, you should try to ensure that a potential divider exists on the input pin directly so that an excessive voltage is not passed through the upper clamping diode to Vcc. It matters not whether your circuit is powered or unpowered.

For ESD surges then it's not a problem but, if 24 volts is continuously present and, your MCU operating current is normally very low, then you need to take care of this situation.

Nothing wrong with using a zener diode across your power rails unless you are worried about leakage current consumption on battery powered equipment BUT, then, that's where your problems are going to happen without a proper input potential divider.

Comment: I can't really use a voltage divider at the input because the expected input voltage range is quite large (between, say, 5-32V). But as I mentioned in another comment, I didn't account for other current sinks on the 3V3 rail, and there are plenty. No problem whatsoever sinking that tiny current coming through the 47 kohm resistance.

Comment: @mairas so, when you asked this question:$$$$ *If the input is still active with a voltage of, say, 12V or 24V, wouldn't the same voltage be present at the MCU input?* $$$$...did you not consider the potential divider effect of the input 47 kohm and the other current sinks on the 3.3 volt rail?

Comment: No, because I didn't think of the sink side at all when I asked the question. :-) It would've been clear to me if I did.

With just a red power indicator LED with a 2kohm series resistor sinking the current and a worst-case input of 32V, the 3.3V rail rises only to 3.0 V. So it's all good, even without considering the numerous other sinks present.

Comment: Well, your question was fairly general and general answers have been given so, it's down to you to apply up-votes and accept one answer as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will not be 12V or 24V.

If that is a schottky diode, let's assume t has a forward voltage of 0.3V when it conducts.

If the 3.3V supply voltage has dropped to 0V, then the diode starts to conduct when input is 0.3V, so only 0.3V is seen by the input pin. The rest of the voltage, e.g. 11.7V or 23.7V is dropped by the current limiting resistor, and very little current flows through the resistor.

The only problem is, the current has to go somewhere so it feeds the current into the supply voltage node, and if there is very little load on the supply voltage; it can make the supply voltage to rise above 0V. Worst thing is if voltage keeps rising until a LED or MCU gets enough voltage and the LED can light up weakly or MCU can try to come out of reset and start running code, even if there is no power supply turned on.

Comment: I just explained that when unpowered, the 3.3V rail is not at 0V but essentially disconnected from the supply. But you have a point - I didn't consider other consumers. My design happens to have a power on LED with a 2k series resistor. That is easily enough to limit the 3.3V voltage and to provide a sufficient return path for the clamping circuit to work.

With that 47k input resistor, there's no way the LED would be visibly lit up or that the MCU would do anything, however.